# edge-layout in graphviz for fixed node positions

Tags: graphviz, dot

I was trying to write my own [little algorithm](https://github.com/stoerr/annealingDottyLayout) for graph layout that only creates a node layout but does not define edge routes. When I use Graphviz to turn the resulting dot file into a graph, the edges are straight lines that cross the nodes and even overlap each other. Is there a way to use Graphviz to layout the edges as nicely as the dot algorithm does, but have the nodes in predetermined fixed positions?

You can see the effect for instance on the following graph:

```
digraph test {
  "a" [pos="0.0,0.0"];
  "b" [pos="50.0,50.0"];
  "c" [pos="100.0,100.0"];
  "a" -> "b";
  "a" -> "c";
  "b" -> "c";
}
```

When drawn with `dot -Knop -Tpng -otest.png test.dotty` the line between a and c crosses b. What I want is that all nodes keep their positions, but the line between a and c goes around b.

Comment: Could you post a sample graph (output of your algorithm)? How do you call graphiz now (command line + arguments)?

Comment: @marapet I've added an example.

Comment: Why does pos attribute page https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/pos/ say that pos is only valid for neato and fdp? Here it's used with dot?

Comment: @WizardofKneup this has the argument -Knop which uses "nop" (no operation) as layout algorithm, since I wanted the nodes not to move. But that was a looong time ago. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add:

```
splines=true;
```

to your graph - result is:

[image: graphviz sline edges]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks! It's just a pity that concentrate does not work in this setting. 8-)