# Edge layout with cgraph for fixed node position

Tags: c, graphviz

I'm using *Graphviz* and *cgraph* to layout some graphs and, for some cases, I already know the positions I want my nodes to be at (as they form a subgraph of a bigger graph).

Using the `dot` command line tool, you can add the `-Knop` [layout option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12896348), but if try `gvLayout(context, graph, "nop")` in my code, or call `gvParseArgs` for `dot -Knop` arguments, the resulting graph has no edge routing, even though I have `agset(graph, (char*)"splines", (char*)"true")` in my code.

Is there any way I can achieve such edge routing for fixed node positions in *cgraph*?

Comment: And if you specify `dot` instead of `nop`, you don't get a segmentation fault?

Comment: No, any of the (standard?) layout algorithms works just fine.